# Future finish succesfully, but data function never executed

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Something is wrong with this code, but I can not figure out what is it.

The problem is that `loading` is executed, and the Future finishes successfully and prints *"From the onPress"*, but the `data` function is never executed so never prints *"Done from the button!!!"*

This is an example that reproduces the problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: MyHomeAsyncValue()),))));
}

final voidFutureProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<void, String>((ref, str) {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () { print(str); });
});

class MyHomeAsyncValue extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyHomeAsyncValue({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('Call'),
      onPressed: () {
        final AsyncValue<void> fromButton = context.read(voidFutureProvider("From the onPress"));
        fromButton.when(
            data: (value) => print("Done from the button!!!"),
            loading: () => print("Loading...."),
            error: (error, stackTrace) => print("Error $error"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**: I tried to wrap the button in a `Consumer` and use `watch` instead of `read`, but the result was the same.

Version flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3

Updates:
Also tested avoiding `void` as the return type, with the same result:

```dart
final userUpdateFutureProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<User, User>((ref, user) async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 100), () => user);
});
```

Update: Created a ticket https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/628

Comment: It could be because your function returns void. That's just at a glance but maybe try having it return something instead?

Comment: Tested as well. No lucky. :(

Comment: Hi @AlexHartford Updated with a simpler example. Looks like the problem only happens using inside onPressed.

Comment: interesting, but i found if use provider for state changing , it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a [ticket](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/issues/628) thinking it is a bug, the author responded really quickly.

Basically, his response is:

> This is not how AsyncValue works. when does not "listen" to
> data/loading/error. It's a switch-case on the current state.

So replacing the onPressed code with the next new code works:

```dart
        onPressed: () {
          final value = context.read(voidFutureProvider("From the onPress").future);
          value
              .then((value) =>  print("Done from the button!!!"))
              .onError((error, stackTrace) => print("Error $error"));
        },
```

So the solution looks to use the inner future to register callbacks.

What is not clear for me is why does the same code work outside of the onPressed?

Here a full working example: https://github.com/angelcervera/testing_riverpod/blob/main/lib/main_onpress_working.dart

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's just helped me with the same problem w. Riverpod 2.0